# Refreshing a AJAX call

Tags: ajax

I have an AJAX call in cordova application.I have checked the availability of internet connection before actual call. But some times in mobile internet connectivity is lost for few seconds after the call is made and thus device does not read any reply from web-service. It goes to error part of Ajax call. I wants to make this Ajax call again so that DOM should get created

call AJAX function is

```
function callAjax(type, mainurl, dataType, data, successFunction, errorFunction){

    if(isOnline == false)
    {
        alert('Internet is not running. Please reconnect and try');
        return 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        async:false,
        type: type, 
        url: mainurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,     
        beforeSend:function(jqXHR,settings){    
           jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
           },
        success: function(data) {
            successFunction(data);
        },
        error: function(response) {
           // alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            errorFunction(response);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retry after an error, you can just re-call your function recursively, or do something like this to prevent too many retries:

```
function callAjax(type, mainurl, dataType, data, successFunction, errorFunction){

    if (isOnline == false) {
        alert('Internet is not running. Please reconnect and try');
        return 0;
    }

    function tryAjax(retryCount) {
        $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            async:false,
            type: type, 
            url: mainurl,
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,     
            beforeSend:function(jqXHR,settings){    
               jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                successFunction(data);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                if (retryCount >  10) {                
                    errorFunction(response);
                } else {
                    tryAjax(retryCount + 1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    tryAjax(0);
}
```

Comment: I have also considered this option but this may leads to infinite loop in certain situation

Comment: @MiteshBaviskar It will not lead to an infinite loop. It will stop after 10 retries.